# Issue with laravel and eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I currently work with Laravel 7 with DB2 database (I use https://github.com/cooperl22/laravel-ibmi for the connection)

I am trying to use an existing database, but I have a problem with some tuples. A character "b" sometimes appears in the results, and I don't know why. Because of this problem, I can't use JSON to work with this data.

[image: b prefix image example]

If anyone has an explanation, I'll take it ! Thank you !

Comment: Can you provide the code that returns this response?

Comment: I just use "php artisan tinker" and try a Eloquent command

Comment: it returns to your database schema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749442/what-does-the-b-in-front-of-string-literals-do#:~:text=This%20%22b%22%20means%20%22binary,where%20all%20strings%20are%20binary.

Comment: What is the *Type* of that column in your db?

Comment: In my db is CHAR(32) CCSID 297 NOT NULL DEFAULT ''